# Formatting Decimals to strings for performance

Tags: java, performance, formatting, decimal

I'm writing an app that needs to output Decimals of varying lengths, and varying scale to strings **without the decimal point** for writing to a flat file as input to another system. e.g.

```
 12345  -> Length:10, Scale:2              -> 0001234500
 123.45 -> Length:10, Scale:2              -> 0000012345
 123.45 -> Length:10, Scale:3              -> 0000123450
-123.45 -> Length:10, Scale:3, signed:true -> -000123450
 123.45 -> Length:10, Scale:3, signed:true -> +000123450
```

The function I have written to handle this is below and is going to be called hundreds of thousands of times so I want to make sure that there's not a better, more efficient way to do this. I've looked at ways to get DecimalFormat to do more for me but I can't see it handling my need to format with decimal places but without decimal point.

```
protected String getFormattedDecimal( String value, int len, int scale, Boolean signed ) throws Exception{
    StringBuffer retVal = new StringBuffer();

    //Need a BigDecimal to facilitiate correct formatting
    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal( value );

    //set the scale to ensure that the correct number of zeroes 
    //at the end in case of rounding
    bd = bd.setScale( scale );

    //taking it that if its supposed to have negative it'll be part of the num
    if ( ( bd.compareTo( BigDecimal.ZERO ) >= 0 ) && signed ){
        retVal.append( "+" );
    }           

    StringBuffer sbFormat = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        sbFormat.append('0');
    }

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat( sbFormat.toString() );

    retVal.append( df.format( bd.unscaledValue() ) );

    return retVal.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My performance-enhanced implementation is below.  It is about 4.5 times as fast as the DecimalFormatter-based solution: running on my machine, using Eclipse with a decent home-brewed test harness, the results are:

- Old way took 5421 ms to make 600,000 calls (average 0.009035 ms per call)

  New way took 1219 ms to make 600,000 calls (average 0.002032 ms per call)

**Some notes:**

- My solution makes use of a fixed-size block of zeroes for padding.  If you anticipate needing more padding on either side than the thirty or so I used, you'd have to increase the size... clearly you could increase it dynamically if required.

  Your comments above didn't quite match the code.  Specifically, if a sign character was returned, the returned length is one greater than requested (your comments say otherwise).  I have chosen to believe the code rather than the comments.

  I made my method static, since it requires no instance state.  That's a personal taste thing - ymmv.

Also: in order to mimic the behavior of the original (but not given in the comments), this:

If there are more fractional digits in the incoming value than fit in scale, throws an ArithmeticException
If there are more whole digits in the incoming value than fit in (len-scale), the returned string is longer than len. 
If signed is true, the returned string will be one longer than len

- **However**: if len is negative, the original returns a comma-delimited string.  This throws an IllegalARgumentException

```
package com.pragmaticsoftwaredevelopment.stackoverflow;
...
   final static String formatterZeroes="00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";
   protected static String getFormattedDecimal ( String value, int len, int scale, Boolean signed ) throws IllegalArgumentException {
       if (value.length() == 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Cannot format a zero-length value");
       if (len <= 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Illegal length (" + len + ")");
       StringBuffer retVal = new StringBuffer();
       String sign=null;
       int numStartIdx; 
       if ("+-".indexOf(value.charAt(0)) < 0) {
          numStartIdx=0;
       } else {
          numStartIdx=1;
          if (value.charAt(0) == '-')
             sign = "-";
       }
       if (signed && (value.charAt(0) != '-'))
          sign = "+";
       if (sign==null)
          sign="";
       retVal.append(sign);


       int dotIdx = value.indexOf('.');
       int requestedWholePartLength = (len-scale);

       if (dotIdx < 0) { 
          int wholePartPadLength = (requestedWholePartLength - ((value.length()-numStartIdx)));
          if (wholePartPadLength > 0)
             retVal.append(formatterZeroes.substring(0, wholePartPadLength));
          retVal.append (value.substring(numStartIdx));
          if (scale > 0)
             retVal.append(formatterZeroes.substring(0, scale));
       }
       else {
          int wholePartPadLength = (requestedWholePartLength - (dotIdx - numStartIdx));
          if (wholePartPadLength > 0)
             retVal.append(formatterZeroes.substring(0, wholePartPadLength));
          retVal.append (value.substring(numStartIdx, dotIdx));
          retVal.append (value.substring (dotIdx+1));
          int fractionalPartPadLength = (scale - (value.length() - 1 - dotIdx));
          if (fractionalPartPadLength > 0)
             retVal.append(formatterZeroes.substring(0, fractionalPartPadLength));


       }

       return retVal.toString();
   }
```

Comment: +1 (although that justly deserves +100 for the effort put in)

Comment: Thanks.  Of course, it was your suggestion in the first place.  :)

Comment: +1 Mate, impressive amount of work & effort so appreciate that. I also took the advice of @ChssPly76 and saw about 4 times improvement in my profiling. If I get time today I'll slot this in and run the stats again and see if there is further improvement.

Answer (score 4):

If you are getting your input as String to begin with, why do you need to convert it to BigDecimal and back?

Seems like it'd be a lot faster to find the position of decimal point, compare that to length / scale and pad the string accordingly.

Comment: I'll try it... looks to me like it'll be more code to do the splitting, padding and handling of signed values but I'm willing to give it a try.

Comment: Looks like a lot more code but is in fact about 4 times faster, thanks Mate.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with ChssPly76 wrt manual String manipulation.

However, if you are going to go down the `BigDecimal`/`DecimalFormat` route, you might want to consider sharing your `DecimalFormat`s instead of creating a new one with every iteration.  Note that these classes are not thread-safe, so if you are using multiple threads to do your processing, you will want to use something like `ThreadLocal` storage to maintain a formatter per `Thread`.

btw, have you tested this and found the performance not acceptable or are you just looking for the most efficient solution possible?  [Note what Donald Knuth says on the topic of early optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize).

Comment: Yes, running it through profiler its average base time was .00058 so the 600k odd iterations it ran through took 349 seconds. I'll have a look at manipulating the string using the lengths and see how that performs, was thinking that would be worse with splitting out and handling negatives.